# Confused on how to prove this matrices with each other

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image]

[image]

So the above picture is the question that I am stuck on. What I tried was to simplify the rows of the matrix on the left but I am always hitting a wall because the entries in the matrix just come unworkable variables for me. I know that I am supposed to get the determinant on the right-hand, then factor our "3" from each row to get "9", but im confused how.

Comment: One approach is to look for a matrix $M$ such that
$$
M\pmatrix{a&b&c\\p&q&r\\ x&y&z} = 
\pmatrix{2a + p & 2b + q & 2c + r\\
2p + x & 2q + y & 2r + z\\
2x + a & 2y + b & 2z + c}.
$$

Comment: alright, I'll try that thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alert:-Brute Force Method-ADVANCE WITH CAUTION-
$$ 9\cdot\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
p & q & r\\
x & y & z
\end{array}\right|=9\left(a\left(qz-ry\right)-b\left(pz-rx\right)+c\left(py-qx\right)\right)=9\left(aqz-ary-bpz+brx+cpy-cqx\right) $$

Now time for the hard one.
$$ 
\require{cancel}
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
2a+p & 2b+q & 2c+r\\
2p+x & 2q+y & 2r+z\\
2x+a & 2y+b & 2z+c
\end{array}\right|=\left(2a+p\right)\left[\left(2q+y\right)\left(2z+c\right)-\left(2r+z\right)\left(2y+b\right)\right]-\left(2b+q\right)\left[\left(2p+x\right)\left(2z+c\right)-\left(2r+z\right)\left(2x+a\right)\right]+\left(2c+r\right)\left[\left(2p+x\right)\left(2y+b\right)-\left(2q+y\right)\left(2x+a\right)\right]= \\
\left(2a+p\right)\left[4qz+2qc+\cancel{2yz}+yc-4ry-2rb-\cancel{2yz}-zb\right]-\left(2b+q\right)\left[4pz+2pc+\cancel{2xz}+xc-4rx-2ra-\cancel{2xz}-az\right]+\left(2c+r\right)\left[4py+2pb+\cancel{2yx}+xb-4qx-2qa-\cancel{2yx}-ya\right]= $$
First we will make 2 equations, first opening the brackets containting the $2a,2b,2c$ parts and then the $ p,q,r$
$$ \require{cancel} I_{1}=8aqz\cancel{+4aqc}\cancel{+2ayc}-8ary\cancel{-4arb}\cancel{-2azb}-8bpz\cancel{-4bpc}\cancel{-2bxc}+8brx\cancel{+4bra}\cancel{+2abz}+8cpy\cancel{+4cpb}\cancel{+2cxb}-8cqx\cancel{-4cqa}\cancel{-2yac} \\
I_{2}=\cancel{4pqz}+\cancel{2pqc}+pyc\cancel{-4pry}\cancel{-2prb}-pzb\cancel{-4pzq}-\cancel{2pcq}-qxc\cancel{+4qrx}\cancel{+2qra}+qaz+\cancel{4rpy}+\cancel{2rpb}+rxb\cancel{-4rqx}\cancel{-2rqa}-rya \\
I_{1}+I_{2}=9qaz-9ary-9bpz+9brx+9cpy-9cqx=9\left(aqz-ary-bpz+brx+cpy-cqx\right) $$

Comment: thank you so much!